# Nuxt - How to Render Child Route without Parent Content

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I am wondering how to display the content of a child page without showing the parent.

I figured this would be straightforward, but I've found nothing about how to do this.  My current output has page 'app/parent' rendering some content for the parent, and 'app/parent/child-A' displays that same content from the parent with the child's content at the bottom.  I'd like to only display the child's content while maintaining the 'app/parent/child-A' URL.

I suspect that I may be approaching the parent/child functionality in nuxt wrong and there is some better option for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: There is indeed probably a better way to handle this. Did you looked into layouts? https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/views#layouts You could also use a `child-a.vue` in your `pages` directory directly, rather than nesting it into a parent folder.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `v-if`

**router.js**

```js
....
const page = path => () => import(`./pages/${path}.vue`).then(m => m.default || m);
const routers = [
   {
        path: '/posts',
        component: page('posts/layout'),
        props: true,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                name: 'posts/index',
                component: page('posts/index'),
                props: true
            },
            {
                path: ':id',
                name: 'posts/show',
                component: page('posts/show'),
                props: true
            }
        ]
   },
   ...
];
...
```

**pages/posts/layout.vue**

```js
<template>
    <main>
        <h1 v-if="$router.name !== 'posts/index'">from parent layout</h1>
        <nuxt/>
    </main>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the proper way to achieve this but it worked for me.

Let's say you have a structure like this

```
pages/
    root /
    parent/child.vue
    parent.vue
    index.vue
```

**root.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
   <h1> Root view </h1>
  </div> 
</template>
```

**parent.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1> Parent view </h1>
    <NuxtPage/> -> Here it renders child view contents
  </div> 
</template>
```

Now if you want to maintain the **'/root/parent/child'** URL without nested rendering. we have to include the parent folder again as optional(or)slug and that page should have its own index.vue file.

**[parentSlug]/index.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
   //Leave it empty
  </div> 
</template>
```

Now the modified pages structure will be

```
pages/
    root /
    [parentSlug]    
        / child.vue
          index.vue          
    parent/child.vue
    parent.vue
    index.vue
```

Answer (score 0):

I handled it like this:

```
pages/
   cars/
      [brand]/
          [slug].vue
      index.vue
   cars.vue
```

**cars.vue**

```
<script setup>
    const showParentEl = ref(true)

    function listenEmit(state){
        showParentEl.value = false
    }
</script>

<template>
    <div class="" v-if="showParentEl">
       parent element
    </div>

    <NuxtPage @toogleParentEl="listemEmit"/>
</template>
```

**cars/[brand]/[slug].vue**

```
<script setup>
    const emits = defineEmits(['toogleParentEl'])

    onMounted(()=>{
        emits('toogleParentEl',false)
    })
    onUnmounted(()=>{
        emits('toogleParentEl',true)
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want you need (in Nuxt3), structure your pages like this:

```
pages/
     parent/
       index.vue
       child-a.vue
     parent.vue
```

Then your parent.vue should look like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtPage />
  </div>
</template>
```